# MS Access Union data filter and criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was looking for a solution to union two tables and count its entries, that is why I have found this piece of code:
[Access union & count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438191/access-union-count)

It works, however, I also need to filter it and add a criteria.

What I have:

Table Inventory

```
Action_A Date_Action_A  Action_B Date_Action_B  Type
Item1    Date            Item2   Date            A
Item2    Date            Item5   Date            A
Item3    Date            Item3   Date            B
and so on, all combinations
```

Table Type

```
Type Team
A    Team1
B    Team2
```

What I was able to code (if Item1 has entries from 03-08-17 and 03-08-17 I have two rows)  :

```
Items Count_Action_A Count_Action_B Date_A   Date_B
Item1  1              1             Week30  Week31
Item1  1              0             Week31  Week31
and so on
```

I need the following table and criteria that only entries added in the same week are shown (entries concerning one item within the same week are merged)

```
Items Count_Action_A Count_Action_B Date_A  Date_B  Team
Item1  2              1             Week31  Week31  Team1
Item2  0              2             Week31  Week31  Team2
```

I need this because later I want to make a graph and filter by a Team, and if possible, also filter by a week.(show entries from week30, or from week30 and 31)

My code (lack of Team column, butit shows me weeks):

```
SELECT Items, Date_A, Date_B, COUNT(A_Type) AS Count_Action_A, COUNT(B_Type) AS Count_Action_B, DatePart("ww",[Date_A]) AS Week_A, DatePart("ww",[Date_B]) AS Week_B
FROM (SELECT Action_A as Items, Date_Action_A as Date_A, Date_Action_B as Date_B, 1 AS A_Type, NULL AS B_Type FROM Inventory
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Action_B, Date_Action_B, Date_Action_A, NULL, 1 FROM Inventory)
WHERE Items IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Items, Date_A, Date_B
ORDER BY Items;
```

[What is in the table and what is displayed on the graph, it does not work as intended.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udVCu.jpg)

**EDIT**

So it seems that I need to always have in a given line the same week  both in Date_A and Date_B.

Right now I have this situation:

```
Items Count_Action_A Count_Action_B Week_A  Week_B  Team
Item1 1              1              Week31  Week31   Team1
Item1 1              1              Week31  Week32   Team1
```

I need to combine Action_A and Action_B into the same weeks, like this:

```
Items Count_Action_A Count_Action_B Week_A  Week_B  Team
Item1 2              1              Week31  Week31   Team1
Item1 0              1              Week32  Week32   Team1
```

Is that possible?

**Edit2**
Grouping process:

```
Items Count_Action_A Count_Action_B Week_A  Week_B
Item1 1              1              Week31  Week31 - OK, stays
Item1 1              1              Week30  Week31 - is transferred to: item1  1  0  Week30 Week30   and   item1  0  1  Week31  Week31
```

**Edit 3:**

I've changed table Type to Type_Tbl, which now has two columns: Type_Typ and Team. And in table Inventory I changed column Type to Type_Inv. So as far as I know at the moment I don't use any restricted SQL words. The problem is with your second query, I got the message "Reference to field "Team" can refer to more than one table listed in FROM function".

Modified first query (no changes in the second one).

```
SELECT Items, TheAction, Date_Action, Week, Action_Type, AOrB, Team
FROM (SELECT Items, Action_A As TheAction, Date_Action_A As Date_Action,  DatePart("ww",[Date_Action_A]) As Week, Type_Inv As Action_Type, "A" As AOrB From Inventory 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Items, Action_B As TheAction, Date_Action_B As Date_Action,  DatePart("ww",[Date_Action_B]) As Week, Type_Inv As Action_Type, "B" As AOrB 
From Inventory)  AS A INNER JOIN Type_Tbl ON Type_Tbl.[Type_Type]=A.Action_Type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer:
We're going to do a 2-step approach.

**Step 1:** normalize the data, join in team, and avoid using SQL keywords as column names. Save this query as NormalizedData

```
SELECT Items, TheAction, Date_Action, Week, Action_Type, AOrB, Team 
FROM 
(SELECT Action_A AS Items, Action_A As TheAction, Date_Action_A As Date_Action,  DatePart("ww",[Date_Action_A]) As Week, [Type] As Action_Type, "A" As AOrB
From Inventory
UNION ALL
SELECT Action_B AS Items, Action_B As TheAction, Date_Action_B As Date_Action,  DatePart("ww",[Date_Action_B]) As Week, [Type] As Action_Type, "B" As AOrB
From Inventory) As A INNER JOIN [Type] ON ([Type].[Type] = A.Action_Type)
```

**Step 2:** properly denormalize and count the data

```
SELECT A.Items, Count_Action_A, Count_Action_B, A.Week As Week_A, A.Week As Week_B, A.Team
FROM 
(SELECT Items, Count(TheAction) As Count_Action_A, Week, Team FROM NormalizedData WHERE AOrB = "A" GROUP By Items, Team, Week) As A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Items, Count(TheAction) As Count_Action_B, Week, Team FROM NormalizedData WHERE AOrB = "B" GROUP By Items, Team, Week) AS B ON A.Items = B.Items AND A.Week = B.Week
UNION
SELECT B.Items, 0 As Count_Action_A, Count_Action_B, B.Week As Week_A, B.Week As Week_B, B.Team
FROM 
(SELECT Items, Count(TheAction) As Count_Action_B, Week, Team FROM NormalizedData WHERE AOrB = "B" GROUP By Items, Team, Week) AS B  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Items, Count(TheAction) As Count_Action_A, Week, Team FROM NormalizedData WHERE AOrB = "A" GROUP By Items, Team, Week) As A ON A.Items = B.Items AND A.Week = B.Week
WHERE A.Items Is Null
```